# Can't create an object with an element of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I'm on python2.7 and I want to get object from specific coordinate in my matrix after initializing all the coordinates at 0:

```
import numpy as np

class test:
    "it's a test"
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=4
        self.y=5

mat=np.full(shape=(4,4),fill_value=0)

mat[2,2]=test()
print(mat[2,2].x)
print(mat[2,2].y)
```

But I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/root/Documents/matrix.py", line 11, in <module>
  mat[2,2]=test()
AttributeError: test instance has no attribute '__trunc__'enter code here
```

And if I change the line 9 into:

```
    `mat=np.zeros(shape=(4,4))
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/root/Documents/matrix.py", line 11, in <module>
  mat[2]=test()
AttributeError: test instance has no attribute '__float__'
```

It works fine for an element of a simple list so I hope this is not due to the fact that I use matrix with numpy...

I hope someone can help me, thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to use `numpy` with custom classes? numpy isn't designed for that use case. Use numerical dytpes or structured dtypes

Comment: Perhaps `fill_value` should be `None`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pay attention to what your statements create.

```
In [164]: mat=np.full(shape=(4,4),fill_value=0)
In [165]: 
In [165]: mat
Out[165]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
In [166]: mat.dtype
Out[166]: dtype('int64')
```

This array can only hold integers.  The error means it tries to apply the `__trunc__` method to your object.  That would work with a number like `12.23.__trunc__()`.  But you haven't defined such a method.

```
In [167]: mat=np.zeros(shape=(4,4))

In [168]: mat
Out[168]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
In [169]: mat.dtype
Out[169]: dtype('float64')
```

Here the dtype is float.  Again, you haven't defined a `__float__` method.

A list holds pointers to Python objects.

```
In [171]: class test:
     ...:     "it's a test"
     ...:     def __init__(self):
     ...:         self.x=4
     ...:         self.y=5
     ...:     def __repr__(self):
     ...:         return 'test x={},y={}'.format(self.x, self.y)
     ...:     
In [172]: alist = [test(), test()]
In [173]: alist
Out[173]: [test x=4,y=5, test x=4,y=5]
```

We can make an array that holds your objects:

```
In [174]: arr = np.array(alist)
In [175]: arr
Out[175]: array([test x=4,y=5, test x=4,y=5], dtype=object)
In [176]: arr[0].x
Out[176]: 4
```

But note the `dtype`.

Object dtype arrays are list like, with some array properties.  They can be reshaped, but most operations have to use some sort of list iteration.  Math is hit-and-miss depending on what methods you defined.

Don't use object dtype arrays unless you really need them.  Lists are easier to use.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation hpaulj, it's really clear now ! It works fine !

Answer (score 0):

You should make explicit the fact that the data type are objects

```
mat=np.full(shape=(4,4),fill_value=0, dtype=object)
```